# What is the proper method for installation of a team site with custom solutions?

Tags: powershell, best-practices, .net

What is the proper method for installation of a team site that has parts and webparts configured using PowerShell as well as six custom C#.NET applications for select webparts?  Should I make a PowerShell config file and run each script in order in a master PowerShell file, or I am supposed to use .NET and an exe file to complete the entire installation of my solution using the PowerShell files as items to be run?  Could you point me to a site that exemplifies whatever answer you give too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what I typically do when provisioning a site:

1. Run a Powershell script which creates the Team site web application, site colletion(s) and configures the technical stuff (Alternate access Mappings, Security, Quotas etc)
2. Run a PowerShell script which creates the lists and libraries and sets their permissions.
3. Run a PowerShell script which installs the solutions on the farm, deploys them and activates them on the site.

So basically, you'll have 3 scripts. 1 is technical, 2 is creating lists, 3 is deploying solutions/features.

I would definitely do everything with Powershell. Here is a good sample to get you started - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gauravbadhan/archive/2011/11/24/deploy-a-sharepoint-project-using-automated-powershell-script.aspx